# Loop on JSON array in bash script and pull data through JQ

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

i want to pull data from jSON file through jq in bash script. I have 50 plus SG objects in JSON .

here is an example of one SG . I want to print a VPC id and group id in one line and so on for another objects.

Solution i tried :

```
jq -c . $old |
while IFS= read -r obj; do 
    vpcidold=$( printf '%s' "$obj" | jq '.SecurityGroups[].VpcId')
    securityidold=$( printf '%s' "$obj" | jq '.SecurityGroups[].GroupId')
    echo "${vpcidold}||${securityidold}"
done > oldtest.json
```

it is working file but giving data in a line by line and want to do more optimised this with for loop.

How can I create a loop on JSON array to get desire output

```
    "SG": [
      {
        "Description": "des",
        "GroupName": "Gpname",
        "IpPermissions": [
          {
            "FromPort": 80,
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "IpRanges": [
              {
                "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
              }
            ],
            "Ipv6Ranges": [],
            "PrefixListIds": [],
            "ToPort": 80,
            "UserIdGroupPairs": []
          }
        ],
        "OwnerId": "123",
        "GroupId": "sg",
        "IpPermissionsEgress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "-1",
            "IpRanges": [
              {
                "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
              }
            ],
            "Ipv6Ranges": [],
            "PrefixListIds": [],
            "UserIdGroupPairs": []
          }
        ],
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "projectcode",
            "Value": "none"
          },
          {
            "Key": "sgid",
            "Value": "sg-123"
          }
        ],
        "VpcId": "vpc-123"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: I'm confused: what's the input, what's the output?

Comment: I want to pull value of VPCid and Group IP from json file.

Comment: @choroba- if you see in my JSON file , you can see there is GroupID and vpcID is given , I want to print this values. This is only one object you can see, similar i have 50 plus object so i suppose we should you for loop

Comment: Can you include at least two instances in the sample? Something like `jq '.SG[] | (.VpcId + "||" + .GroupId)'` might work depending on how the objects organized.

Comment: I have updated the json file with 2 SGs object.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON file is just an array of the objects, you don't need to loop over them in bash. `jq` will loop over them implicitely:

```
jq -r '.[][][] | (.VpcId + "||" + .GroupId)' file.json
```

Tested on the following input:

```js
[
    { "SG": [
        {
            "Description": "des",
            "GroupName": "Gpname",
            "GroupId": "sg",
            "VpcId": "vpc-123"
        }
    ] },
    { "SG": [
        {
            "Description": "des",
            "GroupName": "xyz",
            "GroupId": "sg-12345",
            "VpcId": "vpc-12345"
        }
    ] }
]
```

Output:

```
vpc-123||sg
vpc-12345||sg-12345
```

Comment: Consider filtering any descendant with a GroupId:
`jq -r '..|select(.GroupId?)|(.VpcId + "||" + .GroupId)'`